# JQL for number of changed stasuses and created tasks by every user

Tags: jira, jql

I want to know how many statuses was changed and how many issues were created by every Jira user during the last six months.
I wrote a JQL to get this information by single user:

```
issuekey IN updatedBy(username "2021/12/19", "2022/06/19") AND creator = username
```

But is there is a way to create a query to get this information for all users together?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you repeat/concat the same query, it is not possible to query multiple/all users in one shot in this search function (and there are not many other alternatives), because the parameter does not accept neither wildcards, nor “in (…)” lists, nor functions such as currentUser(), all of them throw an error that an ID must be specified or the user doesn’t exist.

The [JQL documentation](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-work-management/docs/jql-functions/#updatedBy--) is clear that just one single ID can be passed. It is yet to see if the ID could be a perhaps a role or a group (only available to administrators).

Other alternatives are not the same but could be perhaps of inspiration:

1. In order to concat the same query you can use either classic OR or perhaps use the function stacking (Jira Datacenter or Server 8+ editions):

   issuekey in (updatedBy(x), updatedBy(y), updatedBy(z))
2. If you have [SearchExtensions](https://appfire.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/JQLSEARCH/pages/604209933/Issue+Updates+JQL+Functions#UpdatedBy) and the Extended Search app (mostly for cloud, example difference [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Software-questions/JQL-for-Commented-by-user-and-commented-date/qaq-p/1410972)):

   updatedBy in ("helen", "daniel")
3. Explore the [Jira macros](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/jira-issues-macro-139380.html) (inspiration [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/Can-I-specify-parameters-to-use-in-the-Jira-Issue-Filter-macro/qaq-p/1407882)).
4. Finally, you could create your own [custom JQL function](https://docs.adaptavist.com/sr4js/latest/features/jql-functions/custom-jql-functions) for your search, perhaps invoking the original updatedBy, or similar to the [workLogged](https://docs.adaptavist.com/sr4js/latest/features/jql-functions/included-jql-functions/worklogs) function which accepts several parameters, or inspired on membersOf (out of the scope of this answer).

   issueFunction in worklogged("after startOfMonth(-1) inRole Developers")
5. Perhaps building your own search script can help to achieve your request ([here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Updated-by-field/qaq-p/549719) is some inspiration, out of the scope of this answer)

If you liked this answer, give a +1 or perhaps mark it as response.